When coasting to a stop on a manual transmission, shifting into neutral w/out engaging the clutch- can this cause any kind of damage/ premature wear?
Just shifting the shift knob into neutral from 4th or 5th or whatever, not pressing clutch at all. Unnecessary wear or not?

If power is applied to the system, it's unlikely that you would be able to shift into neutral. Your scenario represents performing a shift while the transmission is not under load, which is also the equivalent of pressing the clutch.
I have frequently used this method when coming to a stop. It is also part of performing a shift without a clutch by matching revolutions between the transmission and the engine. The first step is to move to neutral, then to speed (or slow) the engine and engage the next desired gear (lower or higher, respectively). When done properly, no damage is caused.
Important to all of the above is a positive movement, no hesitation. If the movement is too timid, the gears will engage and create damage, but you'll hear it and feel it in the shift lever.
